# Force Word Document ComboBox Item Selection Before 1st Close in VBA

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word, onload-event

I hope that I've asked this question the correct way. I have a Word document used in my corporate environment that managers use fill out certain items for asset deployment. They always fail to add a certain category on the form, so I plan to embed two choices using a Drop Down List control.

However, when the document is opened for the **first time**, I want to force the user to choose an item from the DDL control BEFORE being able to save/close the document. I wanted to know if this initially possible.

So again, **when the user opens the document for the first time**, they can make any other edits, or no edits at all, but they basically CANNOT close the document until the drop down list is populated with one of the two choices. After they make a selection and save the document, the item choice is stored as a constant variable, and they can open, edit or close the document as they choose. Any advice on accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but only reliable if you can be sure no other code might run parallel to yours that could annul the "don't let it close" decision.

The Word Application has events, among them DocumentBeforeClose. This triggers *for every document* that gets a "close" command as long as the event is active. The event lets you do whatever needs to be done before the actual Close takes place. It includes an argument that lets you CANCEL the close.

The reason I mention you need to have full control is because more than one code container can use the event, so whether the CANCEL actually happens when you say it should will depend on which code executes last. As long as you can be sure there's no conflict, the event should do what you need.

Here's a link to the documentation on the event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834271.aspx. It contains sample code that demonstrates how the event works, including cancelling. There's also a link on that page that explains how to set up Application level events in case you're not familiar with them.

Some design questions you'll need to consider:

- Where to place the code: Best would probably be in the template from which the documents are generated, but there are other options
- When/How to initiate the event: Probably in the template's NewDocument event or AutoNew macro. (The event will stop when the last document created from the template is closed, so possibly no need to worry about that.)
- How to distinguish whether a document should be "trapped" by this event: If you're using a template, best is probably to check its AttachedTemplate property and only continue if the AttachedTemplate is the template with the code.
- What conditions need to be checked within the event: You need a way to determine whether this is the first time... What does making the selection in the lists do? Will it have an effect this code can check? Or would it be better to write something to the document the first time?
- You might also want to check the Document.Saved property to determine whether any changes have been made that need saving.